# Eclipse doesnt want to compile code in java

Tags: java, loops, return

here is part of my code:
My eclipse is saying that i need to put a return statment. Why? I have it already, and this loop will always find at least one thread who is alive and return i, so it should end the function and return integer. Would be grateul for help.

```
public int SB(int dealer,int PL){   //
    boolean NotFound = true;
    int i;

    if(dealer != PL-1)
        i=dealer+1;
    else
        i=0;

    while(NotFound){
        if(TH[i].isAlive())
            return i;
        else{
            if(i < PL-1)
                i++;
            else
                i=0;}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You method is declared to return an `int` value. This means you are **obligated** to **always** return an `int` value, not just in your

```
if(TH[i].isAlive())
        return i;
```

statement.

In your case, you return a value if a thread inside the `TH` array is alive. 
What you can do is return an error value at the end of your method that will only happen if no threads inside `TH` are alive.

For example, you can add this statement at the end of your method:

```
return -1;
```

This part of the code will only be reached if your loop runs full iteration. Even if you know there will always be an alive thread and this part of the code will actually never be reached, you need to put it there to humor the compiler.

Also, your loop condition `NotFound` is never updated inside your loop. This means you have an infinite loop in case no threads inside `TH` are alive. You don't really need that variable at all. What you can do is change the loop condition to something like:

```
while(i < TH.length)
```

Or, as it seems the variable `PL` is the length of `TH`, you can put:

```
while(i < PL)
```

This would also protect you from an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` in case `i` goes beyond the length of `TH`

Comment: Yeah, smart as they may be, compiler are sometimes (usually purposefully) dumb :)

Answer (score 4):

Your return is buried in an if statement. What if the if never becomes true? You must have a default return statement somewhere, perhaps as the bottom of your method or in an else block.